# vertical menu with bootstrap and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a menu like this : [Demo](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0048JF7)  .

First of all : Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqdmny41/12/) . There is a button top of the menu and there is a sidebar menu with 4 links that the last one has sublinks.

After click on the button menu get wider.

So far so good. I want to show sublinks with hover when mouse on the last links and also I want to show sublinks below the parent link with click when menu get wider .

I did this, but there is a problem. I want to show sublinks with click when menu get wide.

But now it didn't !

**Here is my important CSS**

```
.rightbar.noneStyle #rightMenu.accordion:hover .accordion-body.collapse{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    display: none;
    height:0;
    position:unset;
    right: auto;
    top: auto;
    visibility: visible;
}

.rightbar #rightMenu.accordion:hover .accordion-body.collapse {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    display: block;
    height: auto !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 61px;
    top: -8px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes in the css and made exactly as you have shown in Demo.
Here is updated code in my
http://jsfiddle.net/sushantmaharjan/z5ogk3yb/

I have used `:not(selector)` in css. Check for the browser compatibility. It works fine in most modern browsers.

Comment: i couldn't do this without your help :) belive that

Comment: are u there ? can i ask u a question ? can i prevent openinig sub menu when is not wide ?

Comment: Currently sub menu is shown only in hover in non wide mode. Although clicking it will open the sub menu but visually it will be seen on hover only and when changing to wide mode the sub menu is seen open. Opening and closing of the sub menu is done by bootstrap by adding class. It cannot be controlled easily. Not easily but definitely not impossible. :)

Comment: They have used different approach on displaying the menu on hover when in non wide mode. When you inspect element and check the the hovered sub menu is removed from normal ul li of nav and is in separate popup div at end of nav tag. So, its totally different approach than the one you are doing.